# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img') while updating my product

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to update my product and after doing it i get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')

The product updates correctly so if i leave the page and come back again, not reloading it, the product is there with the right image.

My Product component

```
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./product.css";
import Chart from "../../components/chart/Chart";
import { productData } from "../../dummyData";
import { Publish } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { userRequest } from "../../requestMethods";
import { updateProduct } from "../../redux/apiCalls";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable,
  getDownloadURL,
} from "firebase/storage";
import app from "../../firebase";
export default function Product() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const productId = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [pStats, setPStats] = useState([]);
  const product = useSelector((state) =>
    state.product.products.find((product) => product._id === productId)
  );
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  const [inputs, setInputs]=useState({})
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [cat, setCat] = useState([]);
  
//   const handleChange=(e)=>{
//     setInputs((prev) => {
//         return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
//       });
// }
// console.log(inputs);
// const handleUpdate=async()=>{

 
// await updateProduct(productId, inputs , dispatch)


// // await axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/products/`$productId`', inputs, productId)
// // .then(response=>console.log(response.data))


//     }
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setInputs((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
  });
};
const handleCat = (e) => {
  setCat(e.target.value.split(","));
};

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const fileName = new Date().getTime() + file.name;
  const storage = getStorage(app);
  const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

  // Register three observers:
  // 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
  // 2. Error observer, called on failure
  // 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      const progress =
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case "paused":
          console.log("Upload is paused");
          break;
        case "running":
          console.log("Upload is running");
          break;
        default:
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    },
    () => {
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
        const product = { ...inputs, img: downloadURL, categories: cat };
        updateProduct(productId, product, dispatch);
      });
    }
  );
};
    
  const MONTHS = useMemo(
    () => [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Agu",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
    ],
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const getStats = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("orders/income?pid=" + productId);
        const list = res.data.sort((a,b)=>{
            return a._id - b._id
        })
        list.map((item) =>
          setPStats((prev) => [
            ...prev,
            { name: MONTHS[item._id - 1], Sales: item.total },
          ])
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getStats();
  }, [productId, MONTHS]);

  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="productTitleContainer">
        <h1 className="productTitle">Product</h1>
        <Link to="/newproduct">
          <button className="productAddButton">Create</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="productTop">
        <div className="productTopLeft">
          <Chart data={pStats} dataKey="Sales" title="Sales Performance" />
        </div>
        <div className="productTopRight">
          <div className="productInfoTop">
            <img src={product.img} alt="" className="productInfoImg" />
            <span className="productName">{product.title}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="productInfoBottom">
            <div className="productInfoItem">
              <span className="productInfoKey">id:</span>
              <span className="productInfoValue">{product._id}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="productInfoItem">
              <span className="productInfoKey">sales:</span>
              <span className="productInfoValue">5123</span>
            </div>
            <div className="productInfoItem">
              <span className="productInfoKey">in stock:</span>
              <span className="productInfoValue">{product.inStock}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="productBottom">
          <form className="productForm">
              <div className="productFormLeft">
                  <label>Product Name</label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder={product.title} name="title"   onChange={handleChange} />
                  <label>Product Description</label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder={product.desc}  name="desc"   onChange={handleChange} />
                  <label>Product Price</label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder={product.price} name="price"    onChange={handleChange}/>
                  
                  <label>In Stock</label>
                  <select name="inStock" id="idStock"
                 onChange={handleChange}
                   > 
                      <option value="true">Yes</option>
                      <option value="false">No</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              
              <div className="productFormRight">
                  <div className="productUpload">
                      <img src={product.img} alt="" className="productUploadImg" 
                   
                      />
                      <label for="file">
                          <Publish/>
                      </label>
                      <input type="file" id="file" style={{display:"none"}}onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
     />
                  </div>
                  <button className="productButton"  onClick={handleClick}>Update</button>
              </div>
          </form>
  
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}
```

My Update component in Redux

```
 //UPDATE
    updateProductStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
      state.error = false;
    },
    updateProductSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.products[
        state.products.findIndex((item) => item._id === action.payload.id)
      ] = action.payload.product;
    },
    updateProductFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
```

Request methods

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
//const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user).currentUser.accessToken;
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user;
const currentUser = user && JSON.parse(user).currentUser;
const TOKEN = currentUser?.accessToken;

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

My routes

```
//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedProduct = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $set: req.body,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedProduct);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    desc: { type: String, required: true },
    img: { type: String, required: true },
    categories: { type: Array },
    size: { type: Array },
    color: { type: Array },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    inStock: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

Comment: Have you checked if the `img` string is correctly saved on your database? Guessing here that, since the product is updated on the client, the error may be at the persistence/retrieval level. Could you make a repro on Repl.it or any online IDE so we can see it in action?

Comment: When i create the product image is stored in firestore but when i update it the image is not stored in firestore. in my mongo db if i create or update the image is stored.